# Java parsing binary data

Tags: java, binary

I have to parse some binary data in Java. Part of my sample file looks like this

```
00000000000000010000000000000100
```

This is 32 bits long and I would like to parse 16 bits as java short. SO I would expect the output be 1 and 4. Code I have written so far is

```
Path path = Paths.get("filePath");
byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(path);

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.rewind();
    ShortBuffer ib = buffer.asShortBuffer();
     System.out.println(b.length);
     System.out.println(ib.get());
     System.out.println(ib.get());
```

This is parsing each value a ascii. and I get the following output.

```
32
12336
12336
```

Can someone help me with this.

Thanks
AM

Comment: Looks like your file contains ASCII characters '0' and '1' - not real binary data. It's actually 32 <<bytes>> long - not 32 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved parsing the String

```
    Path path = Paths.get("filePath");
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String line : lines) {
        System.out.println(Short.parseShort(line.substring(0, 16), 2));
        System.out.println(Short.parseShort(line.substring(16, 32), 2));
    }
```